# Sagemaker Invoke endpoint throwing server error

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, inference

I have deployed a pretrained PytorchModel to an endpoint.. Below is the code

```
pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data='s3://my-bucket/model.tar.gz', role=role,source_dir='model/code',entry_point='inference.py',framework_version='1.3',py_version='py3')
pytorch_model.deploy(instance_type='ml.t2.medium', initial_instance_count=1,endpoint_name='test')
```

I am getting the below error while trying to Invoke the endpoint.. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from primary with message "[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/opt/ml/model'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PyTorch 1.3, there’s no need to specify an entry point and source directory. If you follow the accepted tarball structure, those values are gauged automatically [1](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html#for-versions-1-2-and-higher).

```
model.tar.gz/
|- model.pth
|- code/
  |- inference.py
  |- requirements.txt  # only for versions 1.3.1 and higher
```